# My phaser 3 game is only loading in the font for 1 text strand. i dont know why

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

Whenever my game loads only the score font is updated and its really confusing. i have it setup right in html and in css and js-phaser3. https://ecstatic-ride-d85807.netlify.app/ https://github.com/Grantrocks/tnpg-extension

```
    var DefaultMap = new Phaser.Class({
    Extends: Phaser.Scene,
    initialize: function() {
        Phaser.Scene.call(this, { "key": "DefaultMap" });
    },
    init: function() {},
    preload: function() {
          var progressBar = this.add.graphics();
            var progressBox = this.add.graphics();
            progressBox.fillStyle(0x222222, 0.8);
            progressBox.fillRect(240, 270, 320, 50);
            
            var width = this.cameras.main.width;
            var height = this.cameras.main.height;
            var loadingText = this.make.text({
                x: width / 2,
                y: height / 2 - 50,
                text: 'Loading...',
                style: {
                    font: '20px monospace',
                    fill: '#ffffff'
                }
            });
            loadingText.setOrigin(0.5, 0.5);
            
            var percentText = this.make.text({
                x: width / 2,
                y: height / 2 - 5,
                text: '0%',
                style: {
                    font: '18px monospace',
                    fill: '#ffffff'
                }
            });
            percentText.setOrigin(0.5, 0.5);
            
            var assetText = this.make.text({
                x: width / 2,
                y: height / 2 + 50,
                text: '',
                style: {
                    font: '18px monospace',
                    fill: '#ffffff'
                }
            });
            assetText.setOrigin(0.5, 0.5);
            
            this.load.on('progress', function (value) {
                percentText.setText(parseInt(value * 100) + '%');
                progressBar.clear();
                progressBar.fillStyle(0xffffff, 1);
                progressBar.fillRect(250, 280, 300 * value, 30);
            });
            
            this.load.on('fileprogress', function (file) {
                assetText.setText('Loading asset: ' + file.key);
            });

            this.load.on('complete', function () {
                progressBar.destroy();
                progressBox.destroy();
                loadingText.destroy();
                percentText.destroy();
                assetText.destroy();
            });
            
            this.load.image('logo', 'logo.png');
            for (var i = 0; i < 0; i++) {
                this.load.image('logo'+i, 'logo.png');
            }
this.load.atlas('player', 'character/spritesheet.png', 'character/spritesheet.json');
this.load.atlas('coin','blocks/gcoin.png', 'blocks/gcoin.json');
this.load.image('spike','blocks/spike.png');
this.load.image('dirt','blocks/dirt.png');
this.load.image('idirt','blocks/dirt.png');
this.load.image('bottom','blocks/bottom.png');
this.load.image('edgel','blocks/edge.png');
this.load.image('edger', 'blocks/edger.png');
this.load.image('platform','blocks/platform.png');
this.load.audio('music','audio/DefaultMap.mp3');
this.load.audio('collectcoin', 'audio/collectcoin.wav');
this.load.audio('complete','audio/complete.mp3');
this.load.audio('hurt', 'audio/Hit.wav');
this.load.audio('jump', 'audio/Jump.wav');
this.load.image('sky', 'images/sky.png');
this.load.image('sea', 'images/sea.png');
this.load.image('ground', 'images/far-grounds.png');
this.load.image('clouds', 'images/clouds.png');
    },
    create: function() {
        const createAligned = (scene, totalWidth, texture, scrollFactor) => {
    const w = scene.textures.get(texture).getSourceImage().width
    const count = Math.ceil(totalWidth / w) * scrollFactor

    let x = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        const m = scene.add.image(x, scene.scale.height, texture)
            .setOrigin(0, 1)
            .setScrollFactor(scrollFactor)

        x += m.width
    }
}
            const width = this.scale.width
    const height = this.scale.height
    const totalWidth = width * 10
    createAligned(this, totalWidth, 'sky', 0.1)
    createAligned(this, totalWidth, 'clouds', 0.25)
    createAligned(this, totalWidth, 'sea', 0.5)
    // Place the remaining create function code below
        var music = this.sound.add('music');
music.setLoop(true);
music.play();
            this.cameras.main.setBackgroundColor('#ffffff');
    this.spawnPlayer = (x, y)=>{
        this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(x, y, "player", "1");
        this.player.body.setGravityY(800);
        this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.platforms);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.bottom);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.edgel);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.edger);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.dirt);
        this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.player);
        this.player.score = 0;
        this.player.level = 0;
        this.player.coins = 30;
        this.player.progress = 0;
        this.player.progressl = 800;
            this.player.score = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('score')) || 0;
            this.player.level = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('level')) || 0;
            this.player.progress = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('progress')) ||0;
        this.player.progressl = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('progressl')) ||800;
        this.scoreText = this.add.text(0, 0, "Score: "+this.player.score, {
            fill:"#000000",
            fontSize:"15px",
            fontFamily:"KarmaFuture"
        }).setScrollFactor(0).setDepth(400);
            this.levelText = this.add.text(100,0, "Level: "+this.player.level, {
            fill:"#000000",
                fontSize:"15px",
                fontFaimly:"KarmaFuture"
            }).setScrollFactor(0).setDepth(400);
        this.progresslText = this.add.text(200,0, "Level Up In: "+this.player.progressl, {
            fill:"#000000",
                fontSize:"15px",
                fontFaimly:"KarmaFuture"
            }).setScrollFactor(0).setDepth(400);
    };
    this.collectCoin = (player, coin)=>{
        player.score+=(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        player.progress+=5;
        player.progressl-=5;
        this.player.coins -= 1;
    this.sound.play('collectcoin');
        coin.destroy();
        this.scoreText.setText("Score: "+ this.player.score);
        this.progresslText.setText("Level Up In: "+this.player.progressl, {fontFaimly: 'KarmaFuture'});
    localStorage.setItem('score',this.player.score);
    localStorage.setItem('progress',this.player.progress);
    localStorage.setItem('progressl',this.player.progressl);
    if (this.player.progress >= 800){
      this.sound.play('complete');
      this.player.level += 1;
      this.levelText.setText("Level: "+this.player.level);
      localStorage.setItem('level',this.player.level);
      this.player.progress = 0;
      this.player.progressl = 800;
      localStorage.setItem('progress',this.player.progress);
      localStorage.setItem('progressl',this.player.progressl);
    }
    if(this.player.coins==0){
    location.reload();
    }
    };
    this.die = ()=>{
        this.physics.pause();
    this.player.score-=100;
    localStorage.setItem('score',this.player.score);
    this.sound.play('hurt');
        let deathText = this.add.text(0, 0, "YOU DIED", {
            color:"#d53636",
            fontFamily:"Arial Black",
            fontSize:"50px"
        }).setScrollFactor(0);
        Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(deathText, this.add.zone(400, 250, 800, 500));
        this.time.addEvent({
        delay: 3000,
        loop: false,
        callback: () => {
            location.reload();
        }
    })
    };
        this.anims.create({
        key:"coin",
            frames:[{key:"coin", frame:"0"}, {key:"coin", frame:"1"}],
            frameRate:6,
            repeat:-1
    });

    this.platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
  this.bottom = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
  this.edger = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
  this.dirt = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
  this.edgel = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    this.coins = this.physics.add.group();
    this.spikes = this.physics.add.group();
    this.idirt = this.physics.add.group();
    let mapArr = dmap.split('.');
    let drawX = 0;
    let drawY = 0;
        mapArr.forEach(row=>{
        drawX = 0;
        for(let i = 0; i<row.length; i++){
            if(row.charAt(i)==='p'){
                this.platforms.create(drawX, drawY, "platform");
            }else if(row.charAt(i)==='2'){
                if(row.charAt(i+1)==='p'){
                    this.spawnPlayer(drawX-4, drawY-12);
                }else if(row.charAt(i-1)==='p'){
                    this.spawnPlayer(drawX+4, drawY-12);
                }else{
                    this.spawnPlayer(drawX, drawY-12);                  
                }
            }else if(row.charAt(i)==='c'){
                this.coins.create(drawX, drawY+1, "coin").play('coin', 6, true);
            }else if(row.charAt(i)==='s'){
                this.spikes.create(drawX, drawY+1, "spike");
            }else if(row.charAt(i)==='d'){
        this.dirt.create(drawX,drawY, 'dirt');
      }else if(row.charAt(i)==='l'){
        this.edgel.create(drawX,drawY, 'edgel');
      }else if(row.charAt(i)==='b'){
        this.bottom.create(drawX,drawY, 'bottom');
      }else if(row.charAt(i)==='r'){
        this.bottom.create(drawX,drawY, 'edger');
      }else if(row.charAt(i)==='g'){
        this.idirt.create(drawX,drawY, 'idirt');
      }
            drawX+=18;
        }
        drawY+=18;
    });
    this.physics.add.overlap(this.player, this.coins, this.collectCoin, null, this);
    this.physics.add.overlap(this.player, this.spikes, this.die, null, this);
    this.anims.create({
        key:"walk",
            frames:[{key:"player", frame:"1"}, {key:"player", frame:"0"}],
            frameRate:10,
            repeat:-1
    });
    this.anims.create({
        key:"stand",
            frames:[{key:"player", frame:"1"}],
            frameRate:1
    });
    this.key_UP = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.UP);
    this.key_LEFT = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.LEFT);
    this.key_RIGHT = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.RIGHT);
    this.key_R = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.R);
    },
    update: function() {
     if(this.key_R.isDown){
            location.reload();
     }
        if(this.key_UP.isDown && this.player.body.touching.down){
        this.player.setVelocityY(-350);
    this.sound.play('jump');
    }
    if(this.key_LEFT.isDown){
        this.player.setVelocityX(-200);
        this.player.anims.play("walk", true);
        this.player.flipX = true;
    }else if(this.key_RIGHT.isDown){
        this.player.setVelocityX(200);
        this.player.anims.play("walk", true);
        this.player.flipX = false;
    }else{
        this.player.anims.play("stand", true);
        this.player.setVelocityX(0);
    }
    }
});
```

THis is the right code and the font faimly is KarmaFuture. Any help would be nice so please anyone help.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you have spelling typos for 'fontFamily' in this.levelText, this.progresslText & this.collectCoin